# Is there a way to re-use Eurail's schedule data?

Tags: eurail, timetables

I have purchased a Eurail map and I would like to plan my future trip based on the scheduled trains. The search form on Eurail's website and app are not very practical, and I would like to retrieve the raw timetable data in order to browse through it more precisely. As far as I saw, Eurail's schedule is not available in Open Data (I thought that it was mandatory within the European Union, but maybe Eurail doesn't need to comply to this rule?) and it would be very cumbersome to retrieve raw data for each country separately, when obviously Eurail has already done this job since the app allows to search across the trains of many European countries at once. Since it allows to do this search without an Internet connection, it probably means that the app itself has the timetable list stored on the phone, which is what I'm looking for but it doesn't seem to be viewable as raw data when using the app.

Is there a way to access a raw list of all scheduled trains that are compatible with Eurail?

Comment: Did you check https://www.eurail.com/en/about-us/become-our-partner and https://github.com/juliuste/interrail ?

Comment: @jcaron Thanks for the links. The Github repo in particular is a good start. It doesn't give me the list of all timetables at once as I would like, but at least I can search for them with a bit more flexibility